# Prevent a column expanding based on the content using the grid-template property

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm practising Css Grid and I am creating a layout using the grid-template Property:

```
main{
    width: 1444px;
    height: 70vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template:
    'cas cas cast'
    'cas cas cast'
    'ras  rast rastt';
}
```

According to this, I want the element "cas" taking two fractions of the space and cast only one. The problem is that when I'm putting content in the "cast", the column is expanding taking too much width. I do know that i can set a fixed width with template-columns, but how can i achieve the same with this grid-template property?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify the columns widths in `fr` or they will default to `auto`

```
main{
    width: 1444px;
    height: 70vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template:
    'cas cas cast'
    'cas cas cast'
    'ras  rast rastt';
}
```

Comment: example: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid-template3. If I try here to add the grid-template-column property as you wrote and i add content to the Header section, the width will still grow